# Slow performance with silverlight ClientHttp request

Tags: silverlight, performance, http, silverlight-4.0

I may well be missing something here but I'm noticing very slow performance when using BeginGetResponse in silverlight.

It is taking a large period of time for the callback to fire (10-20 seconds), the requests I'm making are to large resources, but I expected the callback to fire once the headers had been parsed (essentially immediate).

If I take the code and run it on .NET 4 the callback is fired instantly.

Here is the code I'm using in both cases (bar using WebRequest.Create in .NET 4):

```
var url = @"insert http url to large resource here";

var req = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri(url));

req.BeginGetResponse(r =>
{
    var res = req.EndGetResponse(r);

    Debug.WriteLine("Got response");

}, null);
```

In example, a resource that is 10MB in size, 'Got response' can take up to 10 seconds to fire in silverlight.

Comment: When you run the code twice (or more) is it faster the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it downloading the 10MB file in the BeginGetResponse which is why it is slower the bigger the file is. Do smaller file 'get the response' back faster?

Comment: Smaller resources do fire faster, but it isn't downloaded by the time the callback fires. When the callback fires the response stream is just starting to fill up